# Lazy loading tabs with user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, lazy-loading, tabcontainer

I want to use lazy loading of tabs in AJAX tab container. I have implemented it. But the problem that I am facing is that when I click a button or fire any event in that user control, it is not fired; nothing happens.

```
<asp:TabContainer runat="server" ID="TabContainerUp" 
        ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="true" OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainerUp_ActiveTabChanged">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="tab1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <img src="images/uc1.png" alt="" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlUC1" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
        <asp:TabPanel ID="tab2" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <img src="images/uc2.png" alt="" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlUC2" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer>
```

codebehind:

```
    protected void TabContainerUp_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tabName = TabContainerUp.ActiveTab.ID;
        getActiveTab(tabName);
    }

    public void getActiveTab(string tabName)
    {
        UserControl uc;
        //uc.
        switch (tabName)
        {
            case "tab1":
                pnlUC1.Controls.Clear();
                uc = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/UC1.ascx") as UserControl;
                pnlUC1.Controls.Add(uc);
                break;
            case "tab2":
                pnlUC2.Controls.Clear();
                uc = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/UC1.ascx") as UserControl;
                pnlUC2.Controls.Add(uc);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The best tutorial on how to lazy load ajax tab panels: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have already tried it. It is not solving my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recreate dynamically created controls on every postback in `Page_Load` at the latest, with the same ID as before. So you can load and add them to your panels in `ActiveTabChanged`, but you need to recreate them in the next postback in `Page_Init/Page_Load`. Therefor you need to store somewhere what to recreate (f.e. in `Session`).

But i assume that you're making things more complicated than necessary, you could simply create these UserControls even declaratively (on aspx) with an initial `Visible` state of `false`. Then you only need to switch visibility of the controls as necessary in `ActiveTabChanged`.

**Note**: invisible serverside webcontrols will not be rendered at all to the client and no `ViewState` will be saved. So there's no disadvantage in declaring them.

***Lazy-Load*** does not mean that you create these controls as late as possible but it means that you databind them as late as possible. So never bind them to the database from `page_load` (f.e. in the UserControl), but only from methods that will be called when necessary from the page(here from `ActiveTabChanged`). Therefor you could implement a public method `BindData` in your UserControl `UC1`.

Here's a simple example:

```
switch (tabName)
{
    case "tab1":
        UC1_1.Visible = true;
        UC1_1.BindData();
        UC1_2.Visible = false;
        break;
    case "tab2":
        UC1_1.Visible = false;
        UC1_2.Visible = true;
        UC1_2.BindData();
        break;
}
```

and in your `UserControl`

```
public void BindData()
{
    // put here all your databinding stuff 
    // that is in page_load now ...
}
```

This is probably the best tutorial on lazy-loading ajax TabPanels:

- http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html

Comment: If i do visible false then also the tabs are loaded. The user controls are loaded. I don't want them to load at page load time because it makes my page loading speed slow. I am doing this to improve my page load speed.

Comment: @coder311: that's what i've meant with: _"....never bind them to the database from page_load...."_ Make them visible and databind them from ActiveTabChanged not from page_load. They mustn't be loaded automatically but manually only when needed. Shall i provide a sample of the `public void DataBind` method?

Comment: Yes. It'll make me understand better.

Comment: Hi..Tim..I have followed this approach..and i am facing some problem on Postbacking from a control inside a active user control.